# How to match multiple copies of a value?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

F#'s pattern matching is very powerful so it felt natural to write:

```
match (tuple1, tuple2) with
| ((a, a), (a, a)) -> "all values are the same"
| ((a, b), (a, b)) -> "tuples are the same"
| ((a, b), (a, c)) -> "first values are the same"
// etc
```

However, the first pattern match gives a compiler error:

```
'a' is bound twice in this pattern
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it than the following?

```
match (tuple1, tuple2) with
| ((a, b), (c, d)) when a = b && b = c && c = d -> "all values are the same"
| ((a, b), (c, d)) when a = c && b = d -> "tuples are the same"
| ((a, b), (c, d)) when a = c -> "first values are the same"
// etc
```

Comment: For anyone who is interested: "F#'s pattern matching is very powerful". The ML style of pattern matching that F# inherits from is actually deliberately not so powerful. Specifically, ML restricts patterns to so-called linear patterns in order to guarantee that the amount of time taken to match a pattern is bounded by the size of the pattern. In F#, active patterns circumvent this and let you do anything in the middle of pattern matching. The disadvantage is that performance is less predictable. Mathematica takes this to the extreme.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for F#'s "active patterns". You can define a couple of them like this:

```
let (|Same|_|) (a, b) =
    if a = b then Some a else None

let (|FstEqual|_|) ((a, _), (c, _)) =
    if a = c then Some a else None
```

And then clean up your pattern matching with them; note how the first case (where all values are equal) uses the nested `Same` pattern to check that the first and second elements of the tuple are equal:

```
match tuple1, tuple2 with
| Same (Same x) ->
    "all values are the same"
| Same (x, y) ->
    "tuples are the same"
| FstEqual a ->
    "first values are the same"
| _ ->
    failwith "TODO"
```

Performance tip: I like to mark simple active patterns like these with `inline` -- since the logic within the active patterns is simple (just a few IL instructions), it makes sense to inline them and avoid the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [parameterized active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) to remedy the issue.

```
let (|TuplePairPattern|_|) ((p1, p2), (p3, p4)) ((a, b), (c, d)) =
    let matched =
        [(p1, a); (p2, b); (p3, c); (p4, d)]
        |> Seq.groupBy fst
        |> Seq.map (snd >> Set.ofSeq)
        |> Seq.forall (fun s -> Set.count s = 1)
    if matched then Some () else None
```

Particularly, you should define a pattern in a form of literals (chars, strings, etc).

```
match tuple1, tuple2 with
| TuplePairPattern(('a', 'a'), ('a', 'a')) -> "all values are the same"
| TuplePairPattern(('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b')) -> "tuples are the same"
| TuplePairPattern(("a", "b"), ("a", "c")) -> "first values are the same"
// etc
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of overhead to introduce just to eliminate a few equality checks. It may not be noticeable if you only execute this `match` once or twice, but if you use this when looping over some data (for example) it will definitely impact performance.

Comment: Agree. This is a good approach when readability is the key and performance isn't a critical issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the most elegant way can be accomplished by combining two excellent answers provided by @Stephen Swensen and @pad.

The first idea is that the structure (a tuple containing two tuples) can be unpacked once, instead of doing it in every `match` case.
The second idea is working with sequences of values, all of which must be equal to each other.

Here's the code:

```
let comparer ((a,b),(c,d)) =
    let same = Set.ofSeq >> Set.count >> ((=) 1)
    if   same[a; b; c; d]         then "all values are the same"
    elif same[a; c] && same[b; d] then "tuples are the same"
    elif same[a; c]               then "first values are the same"
    else                                "none of above"
```

You may change `elif`'s into a `match`, but does not seem feasible to me.

Comment: Downvoted as (IMO at least), ditching the elegance of F#'s pattern matching in favour of imperitive style chained if, else if's, completely misses the point of functional programming.

Comment: @DavidArno Thank you for the feedback, but `if-then-else` concept even exists in category theory and lambda calculus. Can you please expand why and how it harms the functional paradigm? Also, the `match` is nothing else but an ordered sequence of `if-then`'s.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, I would probably unpack the tuples up-front and then do a series of if / then / else expressions:

```
let a,b = tuple1
let c,d = tuple2

if a = b && b = c && c = d then "all values are the same"
elif a = c && b = d then "tuples are the same"
elif a = c then "first values are the same"
...
```

If you find yourself doing this frequently, an active pattern might be warranted (and in the case of 2-tuples, a [complete active pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) would be doable and likely preferable - exhaustive matches are "safer" than non-exhaustive matches). Or, perhaps you need a more sophisticated data structure.

Comment: Downvoted as (IMO at least), ditching the elegance of F#'s pattern matching in favour of imperitive style chained if, else if's, completely misses the point of functional programming.

Comment: @DavidArno note that in F# `if-then-else` constructs are functional expressions not statements like in imperative languages.